# How much wattage power supply is enough?

Tags: power-supply

I currently have a PC that has a Intel i5-6500, Nvidia GTK 1060 3GB, HyperX Fury 8GB. The power supply I have is Corsair VS550w, but it recently broke, and no longer works. So I am currently using a secondary old cheap power supply I had laying around, that is 450w, and it doesn't have a PCI-e adapter, so I can't connect my GPU to it, so at the moment I'm only using IGPU. I am thinking of upgrading my machine in the near future as well to probably a AMD Ryzen 7 5000 series and 16GB ram GPU might stay the same for the time. But if I'll get a new I'll go with a 1660 or 2060, somewhere in the xx60 series. I'm wondering how much watt power supply should I get now, for future proofing? should I go with 550w or higher? As I do need to buy a power supply right now because I need my GPU to work.

Comment: 550 - 600 W will be sufficient with your plans. You can get IDE / SATA -> PCIe power adapters though.

Comment: Thanks, I bought 550w PSU, working great so far. What are the IDE/SATA PCIe power adapter for?

Comment: You could've used some of the additional connectors (for HDDs / drives etc.) to power your CPU.

Comment: @towe Sorry but I don't understand what you just said. What additional connectors are you talking about? My CPU was powered fine before I purchased this new PSU. There were not enough SATA power connector on the older one, and I could not connect my GPI as it didn't had the PCIe connector.

Answer (score 0):

Enter your desired system specs into an online system power calculator.
Two of the many online are:
https://pc-builds.com/psu/
https://outervision.com/power-supply-calculator

How much overhead you want above this depends on on several factors, some of which are discussed, and some of which are built into the calculator sites.